# Fixed Header is over layed by google map

Tags: html, css, google-maps

In HTML I have a fixed header. A Google map is integrated with it at the middle of page. When I scroll until map the header is fine, when I reach the map, map over lays my header and header is not visible. I'm using basic HTML, CSS codes nothing more.

[image]

Edit :- As suggested by  GvM and dragos.bad 
Try z-index:1 on Gmaps and something bigger on header like z-index:9999
This thing works. 
Thank you everybody.... GvM, JonesJoseph, dragos.bad

Comment: have you tried `z-index`?

Comment: How is the map overlayed? Acc to image  map is still below the header?

Comment: @JonesJoseph i think his header is bigger than we can see in photo and have more content under Gmap.

Answer (score 1):

Without example we can't help you properly. I think you can handle this with z-index.

Try **z-index:1** on Gmaps and something bigger on header like **z-index:9999**. This should make header to be primary visible over Gmap.
If this doesn't work for you, reply on this and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still the same thing. No improvements.